# Angular - inspect return value of method call from injected api service method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, debugging

when I debug to the point indicated below

```
appModule.run([
    "MyApiService", "$rootScope", "$window",
    function (MyApiService, $rootScope, $window) {
        MyApiService.getSomething();
        *debug to here*
        ...
```

The value of MyApiService in the Chrome developer tools Javascript source shows as:

```
MyApiService= MyApiService { $rootScope: Scope, restangular: Object }
```

and I get *undefined* in the console for the value of:

```
MyApiService.getSomething()
```

How do I inspect the return value of `MyApiService.getSomething()`? I know I can use something like this in the console:

angular.element(e).injector().get('serviceName')

...but what can I select as an angular element, since all I'm dealing with in run() is injected dependencies.

(I'd also really like to fully understand what I'm seeing as the value for 'MyApiService' that I see in the JavaScript source output)

Comment: it appears that getSomething() is returning undefined, since MyApiService.getSomething() is a function call - console is showing you the result

Comment: What **exactly** are you seeing in the console? Is there an error around the call to `MyApiService.getSomething()`? Can you not view the source for the `MyApiService`?